# TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'list_iterator' in docplex

Tags: python-3.x, optimization, integer-programming, docplex

Solving 0-1 integer programming problem using docplex solver in python.

```
T_1_d = int((180+8*15-lon-math.acos(math.tan(10547*(math.pi)/81000*math.cos(2*(math.pi)*(date+9)/365))*math.tan(lat*(math.pi)/180))*180/(math.pi))/15)
T_1_d1 = int((180+8*15-lon-math.acos(math.tan(10547*(math.pi)/81000*math.cos(2*(math.pi)*(date+10)/365))*math.tan(lat*(math.pi)/180))*180/(math.pi))/15)
model = Model()
var_list = [i for i in range(T_1_d, T_1_d1+24)]
B = model.binary_var_list(var_list, lb=0, name='B')
model.maximize(A*O*C_0*3600*sum(B[i])/1e9 - Q_0*A/(1000*E)*sum(B[i]*F[i]) - H*D_O*A*P_0/1e4)
```

When I run the code it reports the following error：

```
TypeError: 'Var' object is not iterable.
```

Then I wrote `B = iter(B)`, it reports the following error：

```
TypeError: 'list_iterator' object is not subscriptable.
```

Then I remove the index, turn `B[i]` to `B`, it reports the following error：

```
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'list_iterator'
```

The type of `B` is `list`, the type of `B[i]` is `docplex.mp.linear.Var`. I've tried to `int(B[i])` to change its type, but I failed.

I don't know how to correct. Hoping for your help, thanks!

Comment: Could you post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Answer (score 0):

You did not specify your for loop, rather than `sum(B[i])`, it should be something like `model.sum(B[i] for i in range(len(B)))`.

Similarly for the other summation terms.

Example of code:

```
from docplex.mp.model import Model

model = Model()
var_list = [i for i in range(3, 6)]
B = model.binary_var_list(var_list, lb=0, name='B')
F = [ 5, 6, 7]
print(B)
model.maximize(3600*model.sum(B[i] for i in range(len(B))) - model.sum(B[i]*F[i] for i in range(len(B))))
```